# How many characters will tip the post?

Tags: support, flags, question-quality, automatic-flags

I hear that [abnormally long posts get automatic flags](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2693996#2693996), but I can't find anything on the exact number of characters that will make it flag-worthy.

What is the number?

Comment: The post limit itself is 30000 characters (including whitespace, punctuation... all of them), through I don't know where the flag is triggered.

Comment: This might not be public on purpose, to prevent people from easily bypassing it.

Comment: @Sha That's could be a useful answer to this question - post it as one?

Comment: @Frank was sure someone will do it at some point, done it myself now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a measure against bad quality, most chances are that the exact details are kept secret on purpose, so that it won't be too easy to bypass.

The lack of any official response here also strengthens this theory.

All in all, just avoid posting too long posts and you should be OK. :)

Answer (score 3):

Make your post as long as necessary, and no longer. Ignore any automatic flags or character count limit - as long as your post is good nothing will come of the automated post quality checker's due diligence.

Similar to many other questions feeling out the line between good and bad, the point isn't to see how close you can get without getting hurt, but to stay as far from it as reasonable.  Thus there's no real need for anyone to know the count.